# How the payment methods are rendered and displayed in checkout page in magento 2

Tags: checkout, payment-methods, magento2.2.2, renderer

I wish to know how the payment methods are rendered in checkout page in magento 2

Comment: https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/magento-2-payment-methods/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Refer to the file:-

```
vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\layout\checkout_index_index.xml
```

There look for tag :- `<item name="payments-list" xsi:type="array">`

The code you will be intrested in:-

```
<item name="payments-list" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/list</item>
    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">payment-methods-list</item>
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="deps" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">checkout.steps.billing-step.payment.renders</item>
            <item name="1" xsi:type="string">checkout.steps.billing-step.payment.additional-payment-validators</item>
        </item>
    </item>
    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="before-place-order" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">before-place-order</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">before-place-order</item>
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/payment/before-place-order</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </item>
</item>
<!-- merge your payment methods here -->
<item name="afterMethods" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">afterMethods</item>
    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
        <!-- merge additional data after payment methods here -->
    </item>
</item>
```

Further rendering is done via JS:-

```
vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\js\view\payment\list.js
```

Check their defined utilities:-

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'ko',
    'mageUtils',
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/method-list',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/renderer-list',
    'uiLayout',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/checkout-data-resolver',
    'mage/translate',
    'uiRegistry'
], function (_, ko, utils, Component, paymentMethods, rendererList, layout, checkoutDataResolver, $t, registry) {
    'use strict';
```

The above JS file is called via phtml file located at `vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\templates\onepage.phtml`

In there look for the function :- `getCheckoutConfig`

The data via KO is bind using the html file `vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\payment.html` with code:-

```
<form id="co-payment-form" class="form payments" novalidate="novalidate">
    <input data-bind='attr: {value: getFormKey()}' type="hidden" name="form_key"/>
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
        <legend class="legend">
            <span data-bind="i18n: 'Payment Information'"></span>
        </legend><br />
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('beforeMethods') -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
        <div id="checkout-payment-method-load" class="opc-payment" data-bind="visible: isPaymentMethodsAvailable">
            <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('payment-methods-list') -->
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </div>
        <div class="no-quotes-block" data-bind="visible: isPaymentMethodsAvailable() == false">
            <!-- ko i18n: 'No Payment method available.'--><!-- /ko -->
        </div>
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('afterMethods') -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

If you want to go further deep for methods, and rendering you can look for the JS files inside the folder:- `vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\js\model`

Comment: Thank you @Abdul , Nice explanation , But I need to know how the payment codes are get in list.js  and how  paymentGroupsList function works in list.html