# Magento2 : How to render payment methods on checkout page by default?

Tags: checkout, magento2.3.1

I want to display the payment method list by default. So please help me.
On the checkout page.

In Magento 2.3.1 when I will go to the checkout page then there are 2 steps.

So I want to remove steps and all options must be shown in one step.

I did that but the first time when I will go on the checkout page then payment method list not rendered. Once I click of the next button then It is rendered but I need rendered automatically.

Comment: Please elaborate on your question with your requirements.

Comment: Ok I will update my requirements

Comment: @Sumit added explanation.

Comment: please check with https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/223270/how-the-payment-methods-are-rendered-and-displayed-in-checkout-page-in-magento-2?rq=1

Comment: also this one - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/224702/how-the-list-htmlmagento-checkout-web-template-payment-methods-list-html-is-wo

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/223270/how-the-payment-methods-are-rendered-and-displayed-in-checkout-page-in-magento-2?rq=1  its not working even payment methods go out.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/223270/how-the-payment-methods-are-rendered-and-displayed-in-checkout-page-in-magento-2?rq=1  this is alos not useful

Comment: @AnasMansuri Please give me a best solution mate. thanks in advance

Comment: I found an answer. in js/view/payment/shipping.js    add  get-payment-information action  and then  add this getPaymentInformation(); to into initialize function.   Thanks